# Protobuf issue during TensorFlow installation

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install the TensorFlow version 0.12 which requires Protobuf 3.1.0. I also use Anaconda in which repository there is only Protobuf 3.0.0. How can I upgrade Protobuf and install TensorFlow?

The official website prints out the requirement of 3.1.0 but at the same time it provides the wrong package 3.0.0.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#protobuf-library-related-issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `pip install protobuf`. One can also download the whl package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.1.0 and run

`pip install protobuf-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

Answer (score 0):

I just changed 3.0.0 to 3.1.0 in the URL, so

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

instead of

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Seems to work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall protobuf

pip install -U protobuf
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using poetry you can update protobuf with the right versions `poetry add "probuf@>=3.9.2,<3.20"` and then `poetry add tensorflow`.

The same with pip, upgrade protobuf to the specified version and then run `pip install tensorflow`.